# Can my system get infected by visiting unknown/untrusted website through PhantomJS?

Tags: security, phantomjs

Can my system get infected with something by visiting a website using phantomJS? I don't know/trust the website I'm visiting. And if so, how to prevent it/avoid damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not technically impossible.

PhantomJS uses WebKit as its web browser engine (the same as Safari and many other browsers including earlier versions of Chrome), and it can be compiled against any version of WebKit. This means WebKit is used for parsing and internally rendering a web page.

If the version of WebKit that your version of PhantomJS uses is vulnerable, so will be PhantomJS. If there is something like a buffer overflow or similar remote code execution in WebKit, that can probably also be exploited in PhantomJS too, potentially resulting in a malicious website being able to run code on your computer. These types of flaws (with severity similar to an exploitable remote code execution) are not very frequent, but they happen sometimes. Note that all other, lower risk vulnerabilities of WebKit also affect any version of PhantomJS that is compiled with the vulnerable version of WebKit. What makes this more relevant is that WebKit is used by many projects, so finding and exploiting WebKit vulnerabilities may be worthwhile for an attacker.

PhantomJS itself may also be vulnerable, but the real dangerous thing is parsing the code written by somebody else when visiting the website, and that's done by WebKit. Exploiting flaws in other supporting code in PhantomJS via a visited website would I think be more difficult. Not saying that it's impossible, but the likelihood would I think be low.

As for how to prevent this... The most important thing would be to use a version of PhantomJS that is compiled against a very recent version of WebKit. If there is no known vulnerability for either the WebKit version or the PhantomJS version, you're kind of good to go (but there can always be zero-days of course).

If you are really worried, you could run PhantomJS in isolation. You could set up something similar to a chrooted environment, or an entire dedicated virtual machine. In the latter case the attacker would have to compromise the hypervisor in a completely separate attack, which is probably not impossible, but can be hard, and is very different from any flaw exploited in PhantomJS.

Of course it also depends on what you want to protect against. If you are worried about a compromise of the client running PhantomJS, running it in isolation might be adequate for your scenario. If PhantomJS is part of a larger application and you are worried about the attacker being able to access data in that particular application, you obviously cannot run PhantomJS in isolation from the actual application with the data, so a VM would then not help.

So the bottom line is, yes, it can happen, but it's not very likely, and what countermeasures you need depends on a few things including the risk (what you can lose), and your threat model (what you want to protect against).

Comment: Thank you! I need to crawl 100k of random(=untrusted and probably malicious) websites main pages and save some info about them into a database. The machine it will be running on will contain credentials to other stuff and database will have important stuff as well. So, I didn't want someone to have access to this database/file system.

Comment: I'm not sure how to secure this setup, I'll try to use something like app armor and or something and write data to disk, and then get it with another script into database.

Comment: AppArmor is good, that's exactly the type of thing I meant by something similar to a chroot. With strict rules that definitely helps. Make sure to assign the least privileges to every component in your setup, for example PhantomJS only needs to be able to write a few files or a single database table maybe and it probably only needs to read a few libraries. Then any component that further analyses data could validate its input (which is PhantomJS's output). Using AppArmor with strict rules for the PhantomJS component would I think greatly decrease risk.

Comment: I went with LXC thingy, it has apparmor included. It was troublesome but I got it working in several hours. It's easier to do on ubuntu. Arch linux needs kernel rebuilding though. I've created a shared folder, Host puts the urls there, then calls a script inside the container using `lxc-attach -n name -- command` (it is blocking), waits till the script gets the urls, crawls all urls, and saves a file in that folder with the results. The host then reads the file and ta-daa. I hope that will be enough to stop an infection. Or at least stop an autonomous(without human attacker) infection.